# XQuery - use one value to access another

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to extract the name of all the guides that know English from an XML-document, the problem is that I don't know how. I use XQuisitor to query the XML-document.

Snippet:

```
<GuideLang>
<guideID>1</guideID>
<lname>English</lname>
</GuideLang>
<GuideLang>
<guideID>2</guideID>
<lname>German</lname>
</GuideLang>
<GuideLang>
<guideID>3</guideID>
<lname>Swedish</lname>
</GuideLang>
<Guide>
<guideID>1</guideID>
<gname>John Smith</gname>
</Guide>
<Guide>
<guideID>2</guideID>
<gname>Weber Schneider</gname>
</Guide>
```

I know that:

```
 element Result {
 //GuideLang[lname='English']
 }
```

Gives me all the info about the language and the guide's ID - but how can I use that ID to only print the guide's name from the Guide node?

Thanks!

Comment: This is only an "assignment" from a book I'm reading, and I figure that if I know the answer to this particular question then I'll be able to figure out the rest of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to use XQuery, XPath is fine, too:

```
//Guide[guideID=(//GuideLang[lname="English"]/guideID)]/gname
```

This query fetches all guides whose `guideID` equals *one of the `guideID`s* which are known to speak English and extracts their `gname`.

Make sure to know about XQuery's `=`-operator's set semantics!

Comment: The assignment I'm doing requires the usage XQuery; however, I know that XQuery is an extension of XPath, that makes me wonder if XPath is synonymous to XQuery for such simple tasks.

Comment: How do I get guides who know two languages? I tried with: //Guide[guideID=(//GuideLang[lname="English" and "Swedish"]/guideID)]/gname        but that returns the exact same answer. Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on your data, I cannot decide this from the example data you posted. `(//GuideLang[lname="English" and "Swedish"]/guideID` works fine if you've got two `<lname>`-elements in one `<guideID>`. If you have multiple `<GuideLang>`-elements containing each one `<lname>`, you need to use two predicates in the outer query (or `and`, of course, which is equivalent): `//Guide[guideID=(//GuideLang[lname="German"]/guideID)][guideID=(//GuideLang[lname="English"]/guideID)]/gname`.

Comment: Brilliant, the latter one is working! I honestly tried every probable combination I could think of; and I either got nothing for an answer, or just the answer of the firstly written language. The XML-document was generated with MS Access, so it's a bit primitive I guess.

Comment: @michael-kaesy In XPath 2.0 / XQuery you can shorten such predicates to `[lname = ("English", "Swedish")]`. Writing it with the 'and' the way you did is the same as doing this: [(lname = "English") and "Swedish"], causing "Swedish" to be interpreted as a boolean, which is considered the same as true as it is not the empty string.

Comment: Oh, the unknown problem has turned out to have a simple explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Use this pure XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
/*/Guide
   [for $gid in guideID
     return ../GuideLang[guideID eq $gid and lname eq 'English']
   ]
    /gname
```

This supposes that the nodes of the provided document fragment are children of the (not provided) top element of the (not provided) XML document.

**This can be converted even to an XPath 1.0 expression** (note that no `//` is used!):

```
/*/Guide
    [guideID
    =
     ../GuideLang[lname = 'English']/guideID
    ]
     /gname
```

**Update**:

*Just for the people that are surprized that the first expression above is pure XPath 2.0*, here is a complete XSLT 2.0 - based verification:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "/*/Guide
           [for $gid in guideID
             return ../GuideLang[guideID eq $gid and lname eq 'English']
           ]
            /gname
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the following document** (the provided fragment, wrapped into a top element):

```
<t>
    <GuideLang>
        <guideID>1</guideID>
        <lname>English</lname>
    </GuideLang>
    <GuideLang>
        <guideID>2</guideID>
        <lname>German</lname>
    </GuideLang>
    <GuideLang>
        <guideID>3</guideID>
        <lname>Swedish</lname>
    </GuideLang>
    <Guide>
        <guideID>1</guideID>
        <gname>John Smith</gname>
    </Guide>
    <Guide>
        <guideID>2</guideID>
        <gname>Weber Schneider</gname>
    </Guide>
</t>
```

**the XPath 2.0 expression is evaluated and the correctly selected node is output**:

```
<gname>John Smith</gname>
```

Comment: @Ranon: This is not FLWR -- this is (and has always been) pure XPath 2.0. Check your XPath 2.0 knowledge before downvoting correct answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're totally right. Even checked XPath 2.0 grammar because I was wondering. Don't know how I was able to overlook "for" even in the contents, sadly grepping for "for" is quite useless. :( Anyway, for performance reasons I would stick to predicates and implicit joins as these tend to receive better optimization.

Comment: @Ranon: Agreed, however, using the more verbose `for` expression is a pedagogical means to make an idea understandable, especially for non-experts.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward way to do that, would be something like this:

```
let $english-guide-ids := //GuideLang[lname = 'English']/guideID
return
    //Guide[guideID = $english-guide-ids]
```

The 'let' statement is an XQuery-specific extension of the XPath 2.0 FLWOR statement, but very convenient to keep the code readable.

Some may argue you should try to limit the use of // as much as possible. But XQuery often runs within XML databases, and they are often able to optimize such expressions. For a small assignment, I wouldn't worry to much about performance though..

Comment: Edit: How could I go about only returning the name of the guide with this method?

Comment: @michael-kaesy You were right, the above code returns whole Guide elements instead of just gname's. Just add /gname behind the last ] to fix that. Note that putting the english-guide-ids in a variable prevents looking them up for *each* Guide element as with the solutions from Ranon and Dimitre..